# How to query data based on multiple 'tags' in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, schema

I have three simple tables:

Items

```
ItemID (int, PK)
ItemName (nvarchar50)
ItemCost (int)
```

Tags

```
TagID (int, PK)
TagName (nvarchar50)
```

ItemTags

```
ItemID (int, FK->Items)
TagID (int, FK->Tags)
```

How can I write a query to the effect of 'find all items tagged with tag1 and tag2, but not tag3'?

Do I need to use a completely different schema?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I like to do this with `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`:

```
SELECT it.ItemId
FROM ItemTags it JOIN
     Tags t
     ON t.TagId = it.TagId
GROUP BY it.ItemId
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN t.TagName = 'Tag1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
       SUM(CASE WHEN t.TagName = 'Tag2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
       SUM(CASE WHEN t.TagName = 'Tag3' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```

Each condition in the `HAVING` clause checks for one tag.  The first two use `> 0` to say the tag must exist for the item.  The third uses `= 0` to say the tag must not exist for the item.

Comment: This is pretty neat, and I imagine the group by scales fairly well (vs the outer apply solution).

Hypothetically, if I extneded to 30 conditions, would you still use this approach with 30 sum(case...) statements, or something else?

Comment: @Vok . . . Absolutely.  The `GROUP BY` essentially has constant performance regardless of the number of conditions (the big overhead is the aggregation, not the calculation of another aggregated column).  The `JOIN` method often works better for one or two conditions, but the complex queries can be hard to maintain and can confuse the optimizer.

Answer (score 4):

You can use OUTER APPLY:

```
SELECT i.*
FROM Items i
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT COUNT(*) as TagsCount
    FROM ItemTags it
    INNER JOIN Tags t 
        ON t.TagID = it.TagID
    WHERE i.ItemID = it.ItemID
        AND t.TagName IN ('tag1','tag2') 
) as tt
WHERE TagsCount = 2
```

At first we get all `ItemID`'s with counted `TagsID`'s. Then join with `Items` tables with filtering only those who have `TagsCount = 2`

**EDIT#1**

Add a sample:

```
;WITH Items AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES
    (1,'Item1',100),(2,'Item2',50),(3,'Item3',90),(4,'Item4',63),(5,'Item5',75)
    )as t(ItemID,ItemName,ItemCost)
)
, Tags AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES
    (1,'tag1'),(2,'tag2'),(3,'tag3'),(4,'tag4'),(5,'tag5')
    ) as t(TagID, TagName)
)
, ItemTags AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES
    (1,1),(1,2),            --This
    (2,1),(2,2),(2,3),      --and that records we need to get
    (3,1),      (3,3),(3,4),
          (4,2),            (4,5),
    (5,1)
    ) as t(ItemID, TagID)
)

SELECT i.*
FROM Items i
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT COUNT(*) as TagsCount
    FROM ItemTags it
    INNER JOIN Tags t 
        ON t.TagID = it.TagID
    WHERE i.ItemID = it.ItemID
        AND t.TagName IN ('tag1','tag2')
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 
) as tt
```

Output:

```
ItemID  ItemName    ItemCost
1       Item1       100
2       Item2       50
```

**EDIT#2**

If you want to filter items with no `tag3` tag present you can add left join.

```
SELECT i.*
FROM Items i
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT COUNT(*) as TagsCount
    FROM ItemTags it
    INNER JOIN Tags t 
        ON t.TagID = it.TagID
    WHERE i.ItemID = it.ItemID
        AND t.TagName IN ('tag1','tag2')
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 
) as tin
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT it.Itemid
    FROM ItemTags it
    INNER JOIN Tags t 
        ON t.TagID = it.TagID 
    WHERE t.TagName IN ('tag3')
    ) tnot
    ON tnot.Itemid = i.itemid
WHERE tnot.ItemId is NULL
```

If yo want to filter by some tags you can use temporary table with items that has one tags, and has tags you don't need and then join them. Also dynamic SQL may be an option.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion - being able to use IN is great for extending the list of conditions. I've tried adding AND t.TagName NOT IN ('tag3') but this didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simpler solution

```swift
let filteredTags = Set<Tag.ID>()
```

```
CREATE TABLE sketch (
  id int
)

CREATE TABLE tag (
  id int
)

CREATE TABLE sketchTag (
  sketchId int,
  tagId int
)
```

```
SELECT *
FROM sketch
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT sketchId
    FROM sketchTag
    WHERE tagId IN \(filteredTags)
    GROUP BY sketchId
    HAVING COUNT(tagId) = \(filteredTags.count)
) AS sketchTag
ON sketch.id = sketchTag.sketchId
```