# How to filter items by multiple attribures using eav model?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, entity-attribute-value, anti-patterns

I am building online catalog using eav antipatern. I know this is bad pattern, but i need to be able to add properties at runtime, so i choosed this.Also i cant use solr, because i use hotsted plateform. I have following tables:
Table **values**:

```
id| property_id | value
1   1             rtx3060
2   2             intel i5
3   2             intel i7
```

Table **property**:

```
id| name
1   gpu
2   cpu
```

Table **item_value**:

```
item_id | value_id
1         1
1         2
2         1
2         3
```

```
Table **item**:
id | name
1    laptop-1
2    laptop-2
```

I want to filter items in my catalog by multiple parametrs, like laptop which has both processor intel i5 and gpu rtx 3060. How can i do this with sql?

One brute force way to do this is following:
`select item_id from item_value where value_id = (select id from value where value = 'intel i5') and item_id in (select item_id from item_value where value_id = (select id from value where value = 'rtx3060'));`
This query finds intersection of all ids from item_value table. It can be expanded by `and item_id in (select item_id from item_value where value_id = (select id from value where value = 'some')` to filter by more values. But is there any faster approach?

Comment: Consider something like this: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38954934/how-to-query-data-based-on-multiple-tags-in-sql` ...  Even something as simple as this can be used: `SELECT ... FROM ... your join here ... WHERE value IN ('rtx999', 'other') GROUP BY item_id HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT value.id) = 2;`  This is just a rough hint.

Comment: @JonArmstrong thank you very much, that is what I looked for. There are a lot of suggestions on stackoverflow and people who say that it is impossible but solution is so simple)

Comment: EAV sucks.  And you have just discovered why.  More discussion:  [_Entity-Attribute-Value_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/eav)

Comment: @RickJames, yeah, know , but what if i want to change properties count runtime? Like my ecommerce stroe had 3 categories, and then after some time we added 4-th.  If i use eav, i can just edit properties table throught admin panel and easilty add new category with all it properties,items and their values, etc.

Comment: But if use use other approaches, i will need to cnage database structure, by expanding table or creating new table, and cnage my app code,by creating new entities for table table and so on and so on. Maybe in dynamic languages there is better solution, but in java + spring + data jpa eav is less painful approach.

Comment: @alexsasai - Yes, EAV is very flexible.  The pain comes when you have lots of data and queries are clumsy to write and slow to run.  Maybe "categories" should be a column in the main table, not buried in the JSON.  (Or both places.)  That makes filtering on category faster.

Comment: As for alternatives -- Think of it this way:  If all the data is sitting in RAM, queries are faster than if the data is so big that it has to live on disk.  SSDs help, but I/O is still the main slowdown.

Comment: Another thing...  Avoid "over-normalizing.  Your sample schema has both item and item value 'normalized'.  Those 3 tables should be a single table with just item and value.  Also, if there is a "natural" PRIMARY KEY (that is Unique and unlikely to change), use that instead of adding an `id`.